# Nested it in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

How should I manage nested iterators in Kotlin?
I use a transitional variable, but I'm sure there should be some more beautyful solution for this.

```
arr.forEach {
   val forEachIt = it //I need to get rid of this extra value
   val product = productList.firstOrNull { forEachIt.productId == it.productID }
}
```